# Is it possible to implicitly fall back to parent value for the same key if it doesn't exist on child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Considering the JSON sample below. Is there a way to automatically fall back to parent object key if the key is missing on the child object?

```
// Sample i18n JSON

    "parent": {
      "foo": "foo",
      "bar": "bar",
      "child": {
        "foo": "baz"
      }
    }
```

Is there a way (or a setting) to automatically fall back to parent value for the same key?

```
// Desired usage

$t('parent.child.foo'); // returns "baz"
$t('parent.child.bar'); // returns "bar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
const parent = {
    "foo": "foo",
  "bar": "bar",
  "child": {
    "foo": "baz"
  }
};

console.log(parent.child.bar ?? parent.bar)
```

Comment: Not really implicit, but a decent solution nonetheless. Also, very late. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. If it helps you. Can you please do accept this answer. So that it will be helpful for other developers as well.